# XML file locks sequence file SAP PI

Tags: file, file-locking, sap-pi, sap-xi

This is SAP PI requirement,

- Source System: XY_Client
- Middleware: PI System
- Target system : SAP

The XML files are received to the PI system, for each XML file an internal file is generated to keep track of store_number, and count of xml files.

**How it works**: suppose if XML_FILE_1 reaches PI, internal file called sequence_gen is created. the file contains the store number present in XML file and count will be initialized to 1.
so first time,

```
sequence_gen file contains Store: 1001 Count:1
```

after some time interval XML_FILE_2 reaches PI

```
 sequence_gen file contains Store: 1001 Count:2
```

My question is : If 'n' number of files come at the same time to PI system, the 1st file will lock the sequence_gen file. so how will the 2nd file update the value to the sequence_gen file? So how to tackle this problem?

Comment: You could place the files in a queue and process them after lock on sequence_gen has been freed.

Comment: @UweAllner- how to place file in queue??

Comment: @UweAllner- will sqljet suffice my requirement??

Comment: There will be some Object arriving in your java service (String or File or similar), right? Then you can implement a java.util.Queue, where you put this in. And you have a thread processing this queue and checking the lock state of your sequence_gen file. That's the idea...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save Thread instance in a database using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048053/how-to-save-thread-instance-in-a-database-using-java)