# How to save Thread instance in a database using java

Tags: java, multithreading, sap-pi, sap-xi

This is SAP PI requirement,

- Source System: XY_Client
- Middleware: PI System
- Target system : SAP

The XML files are received to the PI system, for each XML file an internal file is generated to keep track of store_number, and count of xml files.

How it works: suppose if XML_FILE_1 reaches PI, internal file called sequence_gen is created. the file contains the store number present in XML file and count will be initialized to 1.

- so first time,
- `sequence_gen file contains Store: 1001 Count:1`
- (after some time interval)
- If XML_FILE_2 reaches PI, second time,
- `sequence_gen file contains Store: 1001 Count:2`
- and so on..

My question is : If 'n' number of files come at the same time to PI system, the 1st file will lock the sequence_gen file. so how will the 2nd file update the value to the sequence_gen file? So how to tackle this problem?

I thought of creating a thread instance for every call and storing it in a database. and retrieving each instance, performing function, returning result to the xml call and deleting that instance.. Is it possible? How to go forward on this?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? As far as I understand it, after file 1 finishes processing the system will simply move on to file2 (or whatever came in the meantime). That's the basics of asynchronous processing and locks.

Comment: @Buurman- suppose if 100's of files comes at the same time 't0'.. All 100 files will be trying to access sequence_gen file. so wont it move to lock state? will the updated value remain in the sequence_gen file?

Comment: I don't know anything about the specific applications you use so I can't comment on their behavior, but:

In general, if you have some object/sequence/whatever that's threadsafe then yes, it will lock on modification and it will unlock after modification succeeded. It will then contain the new state and the next file comes and can proceed processing with the new state for your sequence. That's basic concurrency.

Have you actually tried your scenario to see if it goes correctly?

Comment: @Buurman- Thanks.. So by use of thread i can lock the file? and release it. I havent tried this scenario, i can test only when it goes-on live.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than keep track of all of the threads that are locking and unlocking the file, you could have a single thread that is in charge of changing it.  Have each thread place a request to change the file into a Concurrent Queue, which then notifies the Sequence_Gen thread to write to its own file.  In essence:

Sequence_Gen thread:

```
@Override
public synchronized void Run(){
    while(true){ //Some condition
        while(queue.isEmpty()) { 
            this.wait();

        }
        Object obj = queue.pop();
        //Open file
        file.write(obj);
        //Close file
    }
}
```

Then, in any other thread, just queue and notify that there is something to write.

```
public synchronized void AddItem(Object item) {
    queue.put(item);
    this.notifyAll();
}
```